# Custom font can't display properly

Tags: applications, fonts

[enter link description here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_other-mso_amobile/how-to-add-a-font-to-microsoft-word-on-an-android/0954c528-44aa-4676-a12a-ff920b184bc0)

I followed the the link and tried to add a new font on my phone on Word. The font displays properly on PC with Word 2007. However on my phone it just likes ordinary font, not the specific one. How ca I solve it?

Comment: What phone are you using? Sometimes changing fonts only works at low level in some devices, others require root to force font to be implemented.

Comment: @xavier_fakerat Hi, I'm using LG G4 with Android 6.0.  My phone seems not rooted since I've tried several root explorer to do it but didn't work. Ibreaa

Comment: I really need a solution.....